# jQuery input allow/block based on div class name

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent "space" from input field. It works fine with present code.

But, if div has classname "name". space will be allowed.

Name input field have to allow space. Policy input block space.

```js
 $('.form-group input').keypress(function(e){
   if (e.which === 32) {
     e.preventDefault();      
   }
 }).blur(function() {
     $(this).val(function(i,oldVal){
       return oldVal.replace(/\s/g,'');
     });         
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 form-group" data-field-name="policyowner_name">
       <div class="form-group__multi name">
         <span>
           <label for="form-firstname" class="visuallyhidden">First Name</label>
             <input type="text" id="form-firstname" class="form-control" name="policyowner_first_name" placeholder="Given name" value="" aria-describedby="policyNameAria">
         </span>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="policy-num col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 form-group has-error" data-field-name="policy_number">
      <label for="id_policy_1" class="visuallyhidden">Policy Number</label>
        <input class="form-control alphanum-input" type="text" id="id_policy_1" name="policy_number">
    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried  `$("input[name='policyowner_first_name']")`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if class is exist or not using   `hasClass` with `this` like below.

```
  $('.form-group input').keypress(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass("name"))
    {
      //Do nothing or whatever you want
    }
    else if (e.which === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();      
     }
    }).blur(function() {
     $(this).val(function(i,oldVal){
        return oldVal.replace(/\s/g,'');
     });         
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can one more condition like `!$("#form-firstname").closest('.name, .form-group').hasClass('name')`. Which will check if any parent div exist with class `name`.

```
$('.form-group input').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which === 32 && !$(this).closest('.name, .form-group').hasClass('name')) {
        e.preventDefault();      
    }
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, oldVal){
        return oldVal.replace(/\s/g,'');
        // Or if you want to allow space in blur also then use following line.
        // return $(this).closest('.name, .form-group').hasClass('name') ? oldVal : oldVal.replace(/\s/g,'');
    });                 
});
```

You can test code below.

```js
$('.form-group input').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 32 && !$(this).closest('.name, .form-group').hasClass('name')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, oldVal) {
    //return oldVal.replace(/\s/g, '');
    // Or if you want to allow space in blur also then use following line.
    return $(this).closest('.name, .form-group').hasClass('name') ? oldVal : oldVal.replace(/\s/g,'');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 form-group" data-field-name="policyowner_name">
  <div class="form-group__multi name">
    <span>
           <label for="form-firstname" class="visuallyhidden">Div with name class</label>
             <input type="text" id="form-firstname" class="form-control" name="policyowner_first_name" placeholder="Given name" value="" aria-describedby="policyNameAria">
         </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 form-group" data-field-name="policyowner_name">
  <div class="form-group__multi">
    <span>
           <label for="form-firstname" class="visuallyhidden">Div without name class</label>
             <input type="text" id="form-firstname" class="form-control" name="policyowner_first_name" placeholder="Given name" value="" aria-describedby="policyNameAria">
         </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if class is exist which is closed div using **hasClass()** with this like below.

```
$('.form-group input').keypress(function(e){
   if(!$(this).closest('div').hasClass('name') && e.which === 32){
      e.preventDefault();   
   } 
 }).blur(function() {
     $(this).val(function(i,oldVal){
       return oldVal.replace(/\s/g,'');
     });         
 });
```